# Swift label isn't changing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

I want change a label when the textfield contains one of the words in the two arrays, when I start the app, if I insert a word of the first array works. Then I insert a word of the second array and also this works, but if I insert again one word of the first array, the label don't change.

```
var one = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]
var two = ["word4", "word5", "word6"]
var count1 = 0
var count2 = 0
let s = textField.text?.lowercased()

    for item in one{
        if (s?.contains(item))!{
            count1+=1
        }
    }
    if count1 > 0{

        label.text = "First array"

    }
for item in two{
        if (s?.contains(item))!{
            count2+=1
        }
    }
    if count2 > 0{

        label.text = "Second array"

    }
```

Comment: 'Label change only one time' is not a useful problem description. Edit your question to include the exact problem you are having, an MCVE, and the expected outcome. Also what have you attempted to solve your problem so far so people do not duplicate your efforts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution myself.

```
var one = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]
var two = ["word4", "word5", "word6"]


let s = label.text?.lowercased()

for item in one{
    if (s?.contains(item))!{
        label.text = "first array"
    }
}

for item in two{
        if (s?.contains(item))!{
           label.text = "second array"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly clear on what you are asking, but one issue with the above code is that you do not reset count1 after the first loop - so if array one contains item, you will set label.text to "Second array" even if the second array does not contain item.

I'm assuming that count1 is declared outside the displayed code, as you don't declare it as a var within either loop. This means the scope includes both loops.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you missed second counter for array two or you better try to figure another solution for this kind of tasks

```
var one = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]
var two = ["word4", "word5", "word6"]
var count1 = 0
var count2 = 0
let s = "word1"
var label = ""

for item in one{
   if (s.contains(item)) {
     count1+=1
   }
}
if count1 > 0{

   label = "First array"

}
for item in two{
   if (s.contains(item)) {
     count2+=1
   }
}
if count2 > 0{

  label = "Second array"

}
```

Comment: I know, when I wrote "..." in the code It's where I have all the code